# Computer wont turn on after turning off

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I have a very specific issue.
~2 months after getting my new computer, I could not turn it on anymore.
So I disassembled it, did a few tests, tried to fix and found out following:

1. Computer runs fine, until I turn it off
2. When I try to turn it on again, it fails, nothing happens, not even fans turn on, but motherboard light is on.
3. If I completely unplug graphics card from MB, put it back in and then try to run the computer again, it starts normally.
4. This happens every time the same.

MB: ASUS Strix B250G
Power: EVGA 500 BQ, modular, 80+ Bronze
Graphics: MSI GTX 1070 GAMING 8G

My only thought is that maybe the graphics card is touching something it should not on MB and because of that its failing. Or maybe the MB is faulty somehow.

Thanks to all,

George

Comment: Try reseating all power cables.